# open file from ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

i am trying to open a file from an ajax call, but it does not open? it works when i type it directly in the browser(http://localhost/home/showfile)?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/ShowFile"
    })

</script>

  public ActionResult ShowFile()
    {
        return File(@"C:\\development\\FileOpen\\FileOpen\\TextFile1.txt", "application/octet-stream", Server.HtmlEncode("TextFile1.txt"));
    }
```

Comment: You need to actually _do_ something with the result of the ajax call.

Comment: yes i would like to open the file

Comment: Open the file in the browser? Meaning what, exactly? Show the file to the user? - How? In a `<div>`? Open it in a new window or tab?

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly clear what you're trying to *do* with the file once you've fetched it, but you can start with adding a callback to `$.ajax` to do *something* with the data returned. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/ShowFile',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);                // log the response, or
        $('#some-element-id').text(data); // dump it into an existing element
    }
})
```

<sub>Do you really need an HTTP post, though? You're not sending anything with the request, so why not just use an HTTP get?</sub>

Comment: i would like to open a dialog box for the user to open /save the file?

Comment: Then you don't want ajax **at all!** Just create a normal link to the file and make sure to send the file with the HTTP header `Disposition: attachment, filename="whatever.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure the file is on your local server because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Then you can use something like jQuery load to load in the file.

```
   $('#destination').load('/path/to/file.txt');
```